# Why We shouldn't use `pub` command directly?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd) says as below.

> Flutter note: If you’re using the Flutter SDK, don’t use the pub command directly. Instead use the flutter pub command

Why? Is it because the version could be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `flutter pub` does more than just `pub`. You can find the source code for the command here in Flutter:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/dart/pub.dart

An example of the difference would be the following comment:

```
/// Represents Flutter-specific data that is added to the `PUB_ENVIRONMENT`
/// environment variable and allows understanding the type of requests made to
/// the package site on Flutter's behalf.
```